# Unknown VST project files

Tags: vst

I am trying to build a VST on Windows, using MinGW GCC compiler, and Cmake build system.

I am using this VST project as an example. It used cmake to build a visual studio project. I am rebuilding the project to work with MinGW I hope!

In the resources folder of the project there is a .rc file, and .vstxml file. I am confused as to what these are. Are the used by visual studio? Are the needed by MinGW?

https://github.com/gijzelaerr/gijzelijzer

Comment: As a github repository, the first place this question should have been asked is that repository. If the README.md or docs pages don't explain what they're used for, an issue should have been filed asking to clarify their role so that people checking out the project have that information immediately available instead of having to find some answer on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The RC file is probably used for the GUI to bundle resources in the VST's DLL. Not sure what the VSTXML file is, but it's probably associated with the GUI again. Regardless, if you are making a GUI-less plugin just to get started, you won't need either of these files.